# Why is git checkout of a branch becomes detached?

Tags: git, github

This is the output of `git show-ref`:

```
84cfc856a refs/heads/master
84cfc856a refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
4131d7214 refs/remotes/origin/foo
84cfc856a refs/remotes/origin/master
```

I have 2 local branches (both tracking remotes on github):

- master
- foo

I know what is a detached HEAD.
When I do `git checkout foo`, I am in branch `foo`.

But when I run:

```
git checkout origin/foo
```

I am in detached HEAD. Why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot checkout a remote branch because you cannot change it. For this reason git says that you are in detached HEAD, because you are not in an actual branch of your repo. You can be there but you are detached.

In order to checkout a remote branch that you don't have locally just type

```
git checkout foo
```

and git will automatically create a local branch that tracks the remote one. And only then you can start doing things.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following situation: at some point, you've checked out the remote branch `origin/foo` into your working copy, creating a local branch `foo` in process. That's usually done just by ...

```
git checkout foo
```

Let's say at this moment `foo` pointer (you do remember that all branches are really just the pointers to specific commits, right?) referred to commit `A`.

Now, you've done some work and committed it to that branch (under commit `A1`). Then some more work. Then some more. So now your local `foo` branch points to commit `A4`:

```
local foo: A4 -> A3 -> A2 -> A1 -> A
```

At the same time someone else have done some work AND pushed it to the remote repository `foo`. Whether it was some merging, or direct commits, doesn't matter; what really matters is that *remote* foo history now looks like this:

```
origin/foo: A4' -> A3' -> A2' -> A1' -> A
```

Now you decide to actualize your local branch (to prepare it for `git push`, for example). The most natural way of doing it is to invoke `git pull origin foo` command - that'll create a merge commit that'll kind of 'unify' two branches:

local foo after `git pull origin foo`:

```
   A4 -> A3 -> A2 -> A1 -
  /                      \  
A5 (merge commit)         A
  \                       | 
   A4' -> A3' -> A2' -> A1'
```

But let's say at this very moment it's not a sensible solution for you to fully merge these branches. For example, you've got to test the *current* state of the remote `foo` on your machine and/or there will be a lot of merge conflicts you're not sure how to better solve.

So what you really need is just to have local copy of the current state of remote `foo` *without* changing existing local same-named branch. And that's exactly what `git checkout origin/foo` is for.

Now, in the perfect world `git` should create a reasonable branch name for this commit (when it's checked out). The only question is, what name to choose? It definitely shouldn't be `foo` - remember, if you want to replace/update that branch, you have other ways to do it. And the other names are potential source for name crashing.

So here what happens: a detached - 'branchless' - HEAD is created. Now it's up to you what to do with it: you can quickly test the changes and merge it into your local `foo` branch just as shown before (as even detached, HEAD now points to a regular commit with its own history), or, if you need some work to do, create a local branch on the top of it with...

```
git checkout -b origin_foo
```

... choosing whatever name you see fit for this commit.

TL;DR - `git checkout origin/foo` is not the same as `git pull origin foo`. They both have their own reasons to be used.